# Fully Generic C++ Stack Implementation Without Lists, Arrays, or Vectors

Tags: c++, template, generics, stack

I'm trying to write a fully generic Stack in C++.  I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Right now I know that the `Pop` method needs improvement since if `T` is a value type, returning a `nullptr` will cause a compiler error.  Also, I'm pretty sure that this can be optimized in a few ways, but I don't see any obvious areas at the moment.  Are there any other specific ways this can be improved?

Any and all feedback is appreciated.

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();
    Stack(T& data);
    ~Stack();

    // Public Stack operations
    void Push(T& data);
    T Pop();
    void Clear();

    // Accessors
    const T& Top() const { return m_top->m_data; }
    const T& Bottom() const { return m_bottom->m_data; }
    bool IsEmpty() const { return m_size == 0; }
    int Size() const { return m_size; }

private:
    template <class T> struct StackNode
    {
        StackNode(T& data)
        {
            m_data = data;
            m_nextNode = nullptr;
        }

        T m_data;
        StackNode<T>* m_nextNode;
    };

    int m_size;
    StackNode<T>* m_top;
    StackNode<T>* m_bottom;
};

template <class T> Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    m_top = nullptr;
    m_bottom = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
}

template <class T> Stack<T>::Stack(T& data)
{
    m_top = m_bottom = new StackNode<T>(data);
    m_size = 1;
}

template <class T> Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    Clear();
}

template <class T> void Stack<T>::Push(T& data)
{
    StackNode<T>* newNode = new StackNode<T>(data);
    newNode->m_nextNode = m_top;
    m_top = newNode;
    ++m_size;
}

template <class T> T Stack<T>::Pop()
{
    if (!IsEmpty())
    {
        T returnData = m_top->m_data;

        StackNode<T>* temp = m_top->m_nextNode;
        delete m_top;
        m_top = temp;
        --m_size;
        return returnData;
    }

    // there is an issue here because if T is a value type, this will cause an error
    //return nullptr;
}

template <class T> void Stack<T>::Clear()
{
    if (!IsEmpty())
    {
        StackNode<T>* next = nullptr;
        do
        {
            next = m_top->m_nextNode;
            delete m_top;
            m_top = next;
            --m_size;
        } while (m_top != nullptr);

        m_top = m_bottom = nullptr;
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do if the caller tries to `Pop` when the stack is empty is to throw an exception. You're right, there's no return value that makes sense.

You have a bug in `void Stack<T>::Push(T& data)`. If the stack is initially empty, the `m_top` and `m_bottom` pointers are `nullptr`, but if an item is pushed onto an empty stack, the `m_bottom` pointer is never set.

There's no reason for `Stack<T>::Clear()` to decrement `m_size` within the loop. Just set it to `0` at any time. (Though, the compiler may be smart enough to notice this)

Comment: Thanks for catching that bug, I definitely fix that.  I'm also going to add the exception to the `Pop` function as well as the accessors. 

I actually like decrementing the `m_size` variable, at least for now, since it makes stepping through while debugging a lot easier (I tested this with 21 elements).

Comment: Thanks for catching that bug, I definitely fix that.  I'm also going to add the exception to the `Pop` function as well as the accessors. 

I actually like decrementing the `m_size` variable, at least for now, since it makes stepping through while debugging a lot easier (I tested this with 21 elements).